# Proof verification in geometry proving that a quadrilateral is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

"Be $ABC$ an acute triangle with $\angle A=60º$ and $AB\ne AC$.
Be $O$ and $H$ the circumcenter and orthocenter respectively of $ABC$ and $E$ the middle point of the arc $BC$ which goes through $A$.

Prove that $AHEO$ is a parallelogram."

This is a contest math problem.

The official solution says this:

"If $\angle BAC = 60º$, then $\angle BOC=120º$. By the definition of $E$, we have that $\angle BOE = \angle COE = 120º$. $OB=OC=OE$, then $\triangle BCE$ is equilateral. Let $M$ be the point of intersection of the lines $BC$ and $OE$, then $M$ is the middle point of the segment $BC$ and $2\space OM=OE$.

$AH  \perp BC$, and $OE \perp BC$, then $AH \parallel OE$ and also $AH= 2 \space OM = OE$. Then the sides $AH$ and $OE$ are parallel and congruent. Then $AEOH$ is a paralellogram.

The step i didn't understand was "...and also $AH= 2 \space OM = OE$"

Can anyone explain me this?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that quadrilateral is a parallelogram.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737609/proving-that-quadrilateral-is-a-parallelogram)

Comment: May I ask what book this is from, this problem seems remotely familiar...

Comment: @user279540 This is a contest-math problem.

Comment: In that case which contest...

Comment: It is a Chilean contest called CMAT. www.cmat.cl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw an extra diameter $AA'$:

[image]

Prove that $BHCA'$ is a parallelogram, we have $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ then it should also be the [midpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Proof_that_diagonals_bisect_each_other) of $A'H$ (see the [possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737609/proving-that-quadrilateral-is-a-parallelogram)).

$AH=2OM$ because $OM$ is the [midline](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/MidlineInTriangle.shtml) of $\Delta{AHA'}$ and $OM$ is parallel to $AH$.

$OE=OB=R=2OM$ because $\Delta{OMB}$ has $\widehat{OMB}=90^\circ$ and $\widehat{BOM}=\dfrac{\widehat{BOC}}{2}=\widehat{BAC}=60^\circ$.

Comment: It is not duplicated, just that i want a proof verification of the official solution. Thanks.